# NoReverseMatch at /'blog' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

I am trying to link two pages.  Page files are home.html and pageOne.html. I am getting "NoReverseMatch at /'blog' is not a registered namespace". I am using django.  When I first created the app, I named it artclBlog, I then created a templates folder and another folder within that one, this one I named blog.  I think I should have kept these two names the same, this may have caused some confusion in my code.

[pic of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdgEW.png)

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog

def home(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects.order_by('-date')
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'blogs': blogs})
```

my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from artclBlog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('<int:blog_id>/', views.PageOne, name='PageOne')
            ]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    pageOne = models.TextField(default='')
    pageTwo = models.TextField(default='')
    pageThree = models.TextField(default='')
    pageFour = models.TextField(default='')
    date = models.DateField(default='')
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

home.html

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
<a href="{% url 'blog:PageOne' blog.id %}">
 <h2 id="txt">{{ blog.title }}</h2>
</a>
    <h4 id="txt">{{ blog.date|date:'M d y' }}</h4>

    <p id="txt">{{ blog.summary|truncatechars:190 }}</p>

    <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Likely the problem is in the *template* of the home view.

Comment: So, this file exists: `path/to/app/templates/blog/home.html`?

Comment: show us your views.home template, also instead of pictures rather paste text of error

Answer (score 4):

You did not define an `app_name` in your `urls.py`, hence that means that `blog:` in `blog:PageOne` makes no sense. You thus either define an `app_name`, or remove the namespace.

## Option 1: Add an `app_name` in `urls.py`

You can specify the namespace by writin an `app_name` in the `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from artclBlog import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('<int:blog_id>/', views.PageOne, name='PageOne')
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This however means that thus all views now use this namespace, including `home` for example.

## Option 2: Remove the namespace

Another option is to remove the namespace in the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
<a href="{% url 'PageOne' blog.id %}">
 <h2 id="txt">{{ blog.title }}</h2>
</a>
    <h4 id="txt">{{ blog.date|date:'M d y' }}</h4>

    <p id="txt">{{ blog.summary|truncatechars:190 }}</p>

    <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help.  I tried both options.  I added "app_name = 'blog'" to urls.py.  I also removed the a tag with the namespace.  However I am still getting the same error page.

Comment: @Lskywaker: but you should not do *both*, you pick one of the two.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I tried both individually, and I still get the same error page.  Right now I have added: "app_name = 'blog'" to urls.py.  Keeping the namespace in the link, removing this would not seem practical because I am trying to link to another page.

Comment: @Lskywaker: likely there is still another `{% url ... %}` with the namespace (or without). Normally if you run it with `DEBUG = True`, Django will highlight the line where it goes wrong.

Comment: @Lskywaker: for `reverse(..)` and `redirect(..)` functions, the same happens: you either remove the namespace, or add it to the `urls.py`.

Comment: I did add the namespace to urls.py.  Like you said, django is highlighting the line where it goes wrong.  It is "<a href="{% url 'blog:PageOne' blog.id %}">" in home.html, like in the original post.  This is very confusing because I did add the namespace to urls.py.  Since I added "blog" as "app_name" to urls.py, like you said in your answer, should that fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This mistake comes usually when you have created different apps in your project.

First you do:

```
django-admin startproject mainapp
```

Then you do

```
python manage.py startapp secondapp
```

`urls.py` in your secondapp folder would automatically have `app_name = 'secondapp'`. However you must add in mainapp `urls.py` the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('secondapp/',include('secondapp.urls',namespace='secondapp')),
...
]
```

This is because your mainapp is the one that has the main access to the project and needs to know your secondapp urls.